# How to contract contact resistance via circuit manipulation?

Tags: transistors, circuit-design

I have a circuit that turn on a LED when the switch is open and and turns off when the switch is closed, now the switch i have is of not so good quality and upon measuring the resistance between the terminals when closed has a 11.3k ohms resistance, this is now becomes a problem because the transistor will treat it as open even through it is closed.

here is the schematics

[image]

I do not want to change the switch (for reasons). How would i manipulate the circuit to accommodate for this contact resistance?

Comment: Use a transistor with higher current gain (say BC337-40) and increase R47 to 33k or maybe more. OR Replace Q9 with an N Channel MOSFET with Vgsth of 2V or less (so Vturn on at 30 mA is < 3.3V and change R47 to say 100k.

Comment: chaging the transistor to bc337-40 did not work in proteus simulations. About the mosfets, i am using digikey's search to look for one that maches your recommendation but i am confused about, `Vgs(th)(max) Id: 2V @10mA` what does `@10mA` mean ? I apologize i am not very experienced with using mosfets

Comment: Did you also increase R47? With say 33K Ib ~= (3.3-0.6)/33k = 0.08 mA. Beta 400 x 0.08 mA = 33 mA Ic. So LED OKish - but whoops Vb with contact closed about 11.3/(33+11.3) * 3.3 = 0.8V. Too high. Need say 68K = 0.45V (probably OK) and I_led !~= (3.3-0.6)/68k x 400  =~ 16 mA. OKish but lower than desired.  darlington or 2 transistors will allow larger  R47 and work OK. || 2V@10 mA (excellent) means at Vgs = 2V Id = 10 mA if desired. ie  very real 2V. What part was that (link?) . A FET is easier than a bipolar as gate current is zero so R47 can be comfortably high.

Comment: yes, i have increased it even upto 150k. here is my [digikey link](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/discrete-semiconductor-products/transistors-fets-mosfets-single/278?k=n+channel+mosfet&k=&pkeyword=n+channel+mosfet&sv=0&pv1291=405400&pv1291=405409&pv1291=405410&pv1291=405416&pv1291=405420&pv1291=405431&pv1291=405436&pv1291=405442&pv1291=405446&sf=1&FV=7%7C2%2C7%7C250%2C7%7C3%2C7%7C6%2C7%7C61%2C606%7C378999%2C1989%7C0%2C-8%7C278%2C570%7C377049&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=50) i have not filled up the Vgsth filter yet under the filter option

Comment: A BSS138 [datasheet](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds30144.pdf) should work  & [pricing](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/diodes-incorporated/BSS138-7-F/BSS138-FDICT-ND/717843) should work well up to over 200 mA LED current (far more than you are wanting). || Using a bipolar, R47 too low will not allow LED turn off, too high and LED current is too low. || The MOSFET is an easy solution. R47 can be say 100k or more.

Comment: I would like to accept you suggestion as an answer sir, replacing the transistor with a mosfet such as the BSS138 with updated values of the circuit. if you post it as an answer

Comment: I did some filtering on my own and came to this [Link](https://bit.ly/2PSCuqu) 1 ( 2 but same part)  of the MOSFET BSS806 had a rating of 2.3A and it made me think it too good to be true, are there any hidden downside to these kind of parts

Comment: No 'real' downsides. You can think up things that may matter somewhat but generally they work well.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon also what is the reference voltage for the gate? is it always ground for mosfets? or is it a case to case basis

Comment: Parameters are specified by suffix to show what they are relative to | Vgs = voltage gate to source. Vds = V drain to souurce. | Vgs_th (or Vgsth or Vgs(tyh) or ...  is the gate to source threshhold voltage where the FET "just" turns on where "just" is usually given as an Ids current. This is usually in the uA range but may be in mA range. eg see page 2 [here](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds30144.pdf) - Vgs(th) is shown as with Vgs = Vds at Id = 250 uA. Vgs(th) is 0.5 / 1.2 / 1.5 min/typical/max so you have a good guide to what to expect.

Comment: BSS806 - 9 cents each in 5 quantity in China :-). About the same as Digikey in volume - around 5 cents. Very good || . | BSS138 1.13 cents in 50s, 0.68 cents in 50,000 quantity :-)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I wont be buying it at thousands quantity maybe just buy a hundred since 50 pcs cost almost the same as a hundred. Would you mind checking out my new circuit and provide feedback ? what could be improved

Comment: You're measuring the impedance with the switch OUT of the circuit??

Comment: @ScottSeidman I apologize if i did not understand your question but if you mean that i tested the switch by setting my multimeter to resistance and the switch not plugged to anything, yes

Comment: @Jakequin If you have not bought any FETs I recommend the BSS806 as vastly superior to the BSS138 EXCEPT that the former is 20V rated and the latter 60V. || Or for about the same price - 100V 2A. Higher Rdson  than the 806 - but still only 0.25V Vds at 1.5A at Vgs = 2.5V - so a lovely logic FET for 3V or 3V3 systems at up to about 2A.

Answer (score 0):

As Russell McMahon suggested i might just change the to BSS138 MOSFET , With that i wont even have to change the circuit much just changing the resistor values.

Luckily proteus has a simulation model for BSS138, here a picture

[image]

R46 in the post can be replaced with a jumper resistor, R47 with a much higher value resistor i chose 500k since at 250k proteus was showing a very feint light at the LED

Comment: 500k higher than needed, Proteus notwithstanding. with 250k Vgs = 11.3/(11.3+250)*3.3 ~= 150 mV. Vgs(th) = ~ 0.5 V at 250 uA - and far less at 150 mV. Look at the typical curves in fig 1 and fig 2. Otherwise cct is fine. For very high  V+ use a gs clamp zener to limit gate voltage BUT not required here. | Try measuring switch resistance with typical operating current - it may be consistently lower than when measured with Ohm meter.

Comment: _Try measuring switch resistance_ are you talking about the actual circuit or in proteus?

Comment: In Proeus you can ONLY SET the resistance. Only in the real world can you measure and then say " the resistance between the terminals when closed has a 11.3k ohms resistance"